# how to pass variables created in R as arguments in a perl program?

Tags: r, perl, arguments

I am new to R. I want to access the variables/objects created in R as arguments for a perl program which is called inside R.
eg: i have written test.R something like this:

```
setwd("some directory")
text <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$")
for (j in text)
{
print(j)
}
system("perl test.pl somearg", intern=TRUE)
```

I need to have the filename stored in "j" to be passed as argument in perl program. how can i access the value of this "j" inside perl program? any way to do this will be really helpful.

thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do and what your end goal is, but another approach might be to write the program in Perl and use the  Statistics::R module to handle the R stuff.  I've been doing it this way lately, and it's pretty slick for simple operations.

Comment: yes i tried it that way too..!! it worked.. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a string to be passed to `system`:

```
system(sprintf("perl test.pl %s", j))
```

The `%s` (s for string) is replaced by the contents of `j`.